# TextFields don't respond when I click on them! It's like they're glued or something?

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

Yo!

I have created a design in the Main.storyboard.
I have a lot of views that I'm using to slideIn/slideOut etc.

The problem is that one of those views have some textfields. None of them responds on click. If I want to interact with them, I have to call 'becomesFirstResponder', but still, the other textfields are not able to respond on click.

I've tried a lot with "bringSubViewToFront" etc, but nothing seems to work. I don't know how to make those TextFields able to interact with.

They're all set delegate, enabled, and all of that.

```
    tv1.delegate=self
    tv2.delegate=self
    tv3.delegate=self
    tv4.delegate=self
```

What else can I try?

Comment: can you share all code?

Comment: Not at the moment but if you wait 30 min I can! The thing is that in this subView where all the textField is, there also is 4 buttons. All of those 4 buttons respond but not those 4 textFields. It's so confusing!

Comment: Make sure each textField and all of it parent views are ‘isUserIntarctionEnabled = true’ in code or with InterfaceBuilder

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Yes sir, all in my app is userInteractionEnabled.

Comment: Upload a minimum working project and provide a link

Comment: Minimum working project? What do you mean?

Comment: @iOS_Newbie9 upload your Xcode Project so that we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: I can create a similar project and upload sir.

Comment: Well, forget that! Too hard to recreate this, also, the project is thousands of lines of code, so I don't want to share it public with no guarantee somebody can solve those shitty textfields.. :P

Comment: It's pretty clear that you copy-pasted the textFields :) we all do that.. make sure each textField has its own outlet ;)

Comment: @Lirik Not sure what you mean there buddy.. but I added the textFields from storyboard so if you think I built up the design programatically you're wrong! But if you don't mind, I would be happy if you could provide a guide on how to design UI programatically? I heared that that's how professionals do :)

Comment: @iOS_Newbie9 I actually meant that you copy-pasted it in storyboard/xib file. When you copy paste controls there, it copies other stuff along with such as outlets. then when you refer to that control in your code it may cause problems.

Comment: Also, it's got nothing to do with professionalism, its about style and taste. I'm personally much more of a visual programmer, so I like using nibs ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RIGHT, FINALLY!**

I do NOT recommend this shitty solution.

But, if you suffer a problem similar to mine, just get it to work with this solution:

1. Add button for ALL of your textFields. Place them where your UITextFields are located and make the Buttons transparent in Attribute-inspector.
2. Add Action to the buttons in your ViewController-class and name them something "textField1_isEditing".
3. Inside the code-brackets, place following: `yourTextFieldsName.becomesFirstResonder()`
4. DONE! Now you can use a TextField that don't respond on buttonClicks, even if you have 100% sure set "userInteractionEnabled" "enabled" etc..